# Как программно делать css Inject chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, css, chrome-extension

Начал делать простенькое расширения для одного сайта. Функционал: инъекция пользовательских стилей на сайт. Загвоздка в том, что это не совсем работает. Если это делается через Content_scripts, то необходимо в стилях указывать !important. Мб есть какой-то JS, чтобы подменять через него? В content_scripts указывается JS с inject'ом, а в самом инжекте непосредственно стиль.

Comment: Ну так приоритет селекторов побольше сделай.

Comment: Т.е?) не сильно понял. Из составляющий у меня только Manifest с style.css в matches и всё, в принципе. Есть ли какие-то готовые варианты inject'а css на сайт через js в chrome extensions?

Comment: Селекторы в стилях поменять не катит?

Comment: Ни разу не катит :)

Comment: Поставить `Stylish` и не изобретать велосипед заново - не?